# Elasticsearch error after upgrading to 2.4.6-p3

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, magento2.4.6, search-criteria

I just upgrade to magento 2.4.6-p3 from 2.4.1 version, when i see the exception.log files, there are a lot of error stating this:

```
main.CRITICAL: Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed
 to create query: For input string: \"7640_7659\"","index_uuid":"pN9D8szyQT6fjQcPbh3_vg","index":"prod24_product_1_v104"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
 shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"prod24_product_1_v104","node":"T9hZWkfdQfqsfGSdu8BvHw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception
","reason":"failed to create query: For input string: \"7640_7659\"","index_uuid":"pN9D8szyQT6fjQcPbh3_vg","index":"production24_product_1_v104","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exce
ption","reason":"For input string: \"7640_7659\""}}}]},"status":400} in /data/vhosts/prod/kw2020/htdocs/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connectio
n.php:694
```

i'm not sure if this related to the product eav or not, but the error trace is coming from  the category page layered navigation

```
/data/vhosts/prod/kw2020/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch-7/SearchAdapter/Adapter.php(117): Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch\Interceptor->query()
/data/vhosts/prod/kw2020/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-search/Model/SearchEngine.php(42): Magento\Elasticsearch7\SearchAdapter\Adapter->query()

/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Search.php(85): Magento\Search\Model\SearchEngine->search()
```

when i checked one of the error log record, it is also showing this:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[term] que
ry doesn't support multiple fields, found [product_attribute_1] and [product_attribute_2]","line":1,"col":261}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:261] [bool] failed to parse field
 [must]","caused_by":{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[term] query doesn't support multiple fields, found [product_attribute_1] and [product_attribute_2]","line":1,"col":261}},"status":400
} in 

/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:694
```

Comment: Please check whether your cron is running or not, and also check elasticsearch connection from store -> configuration -> catalog -> catalog -> catalog search.

Comment: @MitulVadalia my cron is running and elasticsearch is connected

Answer (score 0):

From your exception: looks like Magento creates a query using a string for a number field. You may check (log) the full query before sending the ES.

7640_7659 is not an integer (number).

Here is actual error:

```
{"type":"number_format_exce ption","reason":"For input string: \"7640_7659\""
```

Comment: it's trying to search for two product attributes value

Comment: Then change the type to the string instead. You can change that during indexing.